# Swagger 2.0 semantic error with $ref to path parameter

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor, openapi

I am using [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io) to work on a JSON Swagger 2.0 API definition. I have reduced my definition to a minimum example of the problem I am experiencing. The problem occurs when I use a reference object to define a path parameter that is shared between multiple endpoints.

Example endpoints:
/my-api/{id}/some-thing
/my-api/{id}/some-other-thing

Since these `id` parameters are defined the same way, I abstracted them to the `parameters` section of the JSON file, and included them with `"$ref": "#/parameters/testObjectId"`.

The Swagger reduced definition shows this:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "Test Service",
        "description": "REST API for TestObjects",
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "host": "api.not-a-real-url.com",
    "schemes": [
        "https"
    ],
    "basePath": "/api/test-objects",
    "produces": [
        "application/hal+json"
    ],
    "consumes": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/{id}": {
            "get": {
                "operationId": "getTestObject",
                "summary": "Get a TestObject resource referenced by slug string ID",
                "security": [],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/parameters/testObjectId"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Success",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "default": {
                        "description": "Error",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "testObjectId": {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "format": "slug",
            "description": "Immutable, unique identifier of a TestObject"
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
    }
}
```

But when this is rendered in Swagger, I get the following error:

```
Errors

Semantic error at paths./{id}
Declared path parameter "id" needs to be defined as a path parameter at either the path or operation level
```

The problem is that `id` is actually defined, only it appears that the check which throws this error is occurring before the `$ref` is included. The Swagger output looks correct.

Further, I have used this approach for about 6 months (as long as I have used Swagger) and I am just now running into the problem for the first time. Is there something I should be doing differently to prevent this error? Am I misusing Swagger by doing it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spec is valid. It [was a bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1614) introduced in Swagger Editor v.3.2.2, it was fixed in v.3.2.3 (released on January 6, 2018).